# 5 digits numbers such that when the sum of digits divided by 4 leaves remainder 2.

Tags: number-theory, permutations, combinations

How many 5 digits numbers such that when the sum of digit divided by 4 leaves remainder 2.

Example:-
Consider a 5 digit number-
$(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)$
Then $(x1+x2+x3+x4+x5)$ must be of form $(4n+2)$

I tried this
(x+x²+x³...+x^9)(1+x+x²+x³....+x^9)⁴

In this sum of coefficient of x^(2,6,10,14....42)

But this involve lot of calculation.!

Please some one provide me something different and smarter solution.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I edited my question?? See what i did!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: In case anybody's interested, I did a count: of the five-digit numbers, there are $22500$ with sum of digits equal to $0$ mod $4$; $22498$ equal to $1$ mod $4$; $22500$ equal to $2$ mod $4$; and $22502$ equal to $3$ mod $4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call digits $0$ and $1$ *small*, and digits $2-9$ *large*.

Given $n\ge 1$, we divide the $n$-digit numbers into two sets: $S$, which contains all numbers consisting entirely of the small digits $0$ and $1$; and $L$, which contains all other numbers. Note that:

- $|S|=2^{n-1}$, because each digit apart from the initial $1$ is either $0$ or $1$;
- $|L|=9\cdot 10^{n-1}-|S|$, because there are $9\cdot 10^{n-1}$ $n$-digit numbers in total.

Now, if $c$ and $d$ are large digits, then the number of numbers whose first large digit is $c$ is equal to the number of numbers whose first large digit is $d$. And because the large digits are evenly distributed modulo $4$, this means that the digit sums of the numbers in $L$ are also evenly distributed modulo $4$. So the number of numbers in $L$ with a given digit sum modulo $4$ is $|L|/4$.

This just leaves $S$. But this is easy: the number of numbers in $S$ with digit sum $k$ is the number of ways of choosing $k-1$ positions for the $1$'s (given that the first digit has to be $1$). This is the binomial coefficient $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.

Thus we see that the number of $n$-digit numbers with a digit sum equal to $m$ mod $4$ is equal to $|L|/4+\sum_k\binom{n-1}{k-1}$, where the sum is taken over all $k$ with $1\le k\le n$ and $k\equiv m$ mod $4$.

Here is a table of the number of $n$-digit numbers with a given digit sum modulo $4$, for $n=1$ to $6$:
$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
n & |L|/4 & 0\bmod 4 & 1\bmod 4 & 2\bmod 4 & 3\bmod 4 \\
\hline
1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 2\\
2 & 22 & 22 & 23 & 23 & 22\\
3 & 224 & 224 & 225 &226 &225\\
4 & 2248 & 2249 & 2249 & 2251 & 2251\\
5 & 22496 & 22500 & 22498 & \color{red}{22500} & 22502\\
6 & 224992 & 225002 & 224998 & 224998 & 225002\\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Interesting method! +1.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing your thought of line (using generating functions): for $n\in \{0,1,...,10\}$:

$$[x^{4n+2}](x+x^2+x^3...+x^9)(1+x+x^2+x^3....+x^9)^4=\\
[x^{4n+1}]\left(\frac{1-x^{9}}{1-x}\right)\left(\frac{1-x^{10}}{1-x}\right)^4=\\
[x^{4n+1}](1-x^{9})(1-x^{10})^4(1-x)^{-5}=\\
[x^{4n+1}]\sum_{i=0}^{1}{1\choose i}(-x^9)^i\sum_{j=0}^4{4\choose j}(-x^{10})^j\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{4+k\choose k}x^k.$$
Cases for $n=0,1,....,10$ and $(i,j,k)$:
$$\begin{array}{c|l|r} 
4n+1&(i,j,k)&\text{Total}\\
\hline
1&(0,0,1)&5\\
5&(0,0,5)& 126\\
9&(0,0,9)-(1,0,0)&714\\
13&(0,0,13)-(0,1,3)-(1,0,4)&2,170\\
17&(0,0,17)-(0,1,7)-(1,0,8)&4,170\\
21&(0,0,21)-(0,1,11)+(0,2,1)-(1,0,12)+(1,1,2)&5,460\\
25&(0,0,25)-(0,1,15)+(0,2,5)-(1,0,16)+(1,1,6)&4,998\\
29&(0,0,29)-(0,1,19)+(0,2,9)-(1,0,20)+(1,1,10)-\\
&(1,2,0)&3,162\\
33&(0,0,33)-(0,1,23)+(0,2,13)-(0,3,3)-(1,0,24)+\\
&(1,1,14)-(1,2,4)&1,330\\
37&(0,0,37)-(0,1,27)+(0,2,17)-(0,3,7)-(1,0,28)+\\
&(1,1,18)-(1,2,8)&330\\
41&(0,0,41)-(0,1,31)+(0,2,21)-(0,3,11)+(0,4,1)-\\
&(1,0,32)+(1,1,22)-(1,2,12)+(1,3,2)&35\\
\hline
\text{Total}&&22,500\\
\end{array}$$
Likewise, all four options ($0,1,2,3 \mod 4$):
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
n&4n-1&4n&4n+1&4n+2\\
\hline
0&-&1&5&15\\
1&35&70&126&210\\
2&330&495&714&992\\
3&1330&1725&2170&2654\\
4&3162&3675&4170&4620\\
5&4998&5283&5460&5520\\
6&5460&5283&4998&4620\\
7&4170&3575&3162&2654\\
8&2170&1725&1330&992\\
9&714&495&330&210\\
10&126&70&35&15\\
11&5&1&-&-\\
\hline
\text{Total}&22500&22498&22500&22502\end{array}$$
Note: Although I used a calculator for binomials, it was like digging a well with a needle. I wonder if this method can be simplified in any way?!

Comment: Sir the question say that:-.     Let a five digit no. Be (x1,x2,x3,x4,x5).         And according to the condition (x1+x2+x3+x4+x5)=4n+2

Comment: oops, sorry, misread

Comment: You gave the result for numbers which lie between 9999-99999  and which is of form 4n+2

Comment: But $402,842$ is more than the total number of five-digit numbers...

Comment: @TonyK, corrected, thanks

Comment: By this logic, there are $90$ two-digit numbers, each of whose digit sum is equally likely to be $0,1,2,$ or $3$ mod $4$. Hence there are $90/4=22\frac12$ two-digit numbers whose sum of digits is equal to $2$ mod $4$... So this logic is flawed.

Comment: @TonyK, you can't generalize like that. The equally likely works as follows: in the range $0-39$ there are four sets of $10$ numbers that are $0,1,2,3 \mod 4$ each; similarly in the range $0-79$ there are four sets of $20$ numbers, etc. So, the range $10000-99999$ is the difference between $0-99999$ and $0-9999$, which is $25,000-2,500=22,500$. However, for the range you are considering $10-99$, the difference is $0-9$ and $0-99$ does not apply, because $10$ is not divisible by $4$, though $100$ is divisible by $4$.

Comment: You are wrong that each of the digit sums of the five-digit numbers is equally likely mod $4$. I have counted them, and there are $22498$ equal to $1$ mod $4$, and $22502$ equal to $3$ mod $4$.

Comment: @TonyK, how did you count? I suspect you miscalculated somewhere. Using the accepted answer's method, the series for 0: $2,2,3,3,2,2,...$, for 1: $3,2,2,3,3,2,...$, for 2: $3,3,2,2,3,3,...$ and for 3: $2,3,3,2,2,3,...$. Note that for 1 and 3: $3+2+2+3=10=2+3+3+2$.

Comment: @farruhota: But the sequence is not periodic. After $10090-10099$ comes $11000-11009$, which breaks the regularity. The sequence for $1$ mod $4$ is $3\; 2\; 2\; 3\; 3\; 2\; 2\; 3\; 3\; 2\; 2\; 2\; 3\; 3...$ (I counted the numbers with a simple Basic program, btw.)

Comment: @TonyK, yes, it looks it is not periodic and not equally likely. I tediously completed the calculation with the generating function.

Comment: "I wonder if this method can be simplified in any way?" The computation is actually quite simple, and can easily be done by hand -- see my answer.

Comment: you and @TonyK I respect your work. Thanks

Comment: @TonyK, thank you for discussion. When I said "this method" I meant "the generating functions method". I used three binomial terms, so, I was wondering if it could be reduced to two terms and less computation.

Answer (score -1):

Let us first see the required numbers in

$10000-10010$

**One or two digit number in front of five digit number represent the sum of digits of the five digit number**

$10000-1

10001-2

10002-3

10003-4

10004-5

10005-6

10006-7

10007-8

10008-9

10009-10$

Number of required number in the above series are 3. 
If we see the next series(2) of next 10 numbers. The required numbers are 3. And same for the series(3) (From 10020-10029) number of requires numbers are 2. And for fourth series no. Of required numbers are 2.

And the sequence of required numbers per ten first ten digits is-

$3 3 2 2 3 3 2 2 3 3 2 2......3 3 2 2$

Total number between $10000-99999$ are $90000$.

No.s of 2's and 3's are
=$\frac{90000}{10}=9000$

No.s of 2's  or 3's are 
$\frac{9000}2=4500$

Therefore the required no.s are 
$$4500*(2+3)=22500$$

Comment: Hope! You get my answer!

Comment: The only reason that this gets the right answer is luck, I'm afraid. The sequence is not periodic, because going from $10099$ to $11000$ etc. breaks the regularity. The sequence starts $3\;3\;2\;2\;3\;3\;2\;2\;3\;3\;3\;2\;2\;3...$

Comment: @TonyK From starting, the sequence start from 10000. For any particular period say 10099 to 11000 you have to start with 10100 till 10999. 10099 lie in former phase and 11000 lie in latter phase.

Comment: You seem to have missed my point. Perhaps you should read my comments to farruhota's answer (and my comment to the OP).

Comment: @TonyK you not even get what i did? I read your comments. Let me re-edit my answer. Then it might get you.

Comment: The eleventh number in that sequence (from $11000$ to $11009$) is $3$, not $2$. Try it and see.

Comment: Umang, would you say that your method gives the right answer ($22498$) for the number of $5$-digit numbers with digit sum equal to $1$ mod $4$?